# Searching for geoprocessing tools in Search Window of ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, search-window

I am just trying to search for tools in the Search Window in ArcMap as I've done it earlier and it perfectly worked. After writing the name of the tool, it says it cannot find it but I can choose it in Arctoolbox.

How can I fix it?

[image][image]

It is just way easier to use search box.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your installation of ArcGIS? Because when I search for Apply in the Tools section, I get 15 results, the 2nd one being Apply Symbology From Layer. BTW, maybe you could scale down your screenshot to say, 30%, it will still be readable but not take up so much space.

Comment: Perhaps the search index is messed up. You could try to delete the index, and hopefully have it rebuilt automatically: Click on the button left of 'Local Search' ('Search Options') to do that.

Comment: @Berend this worked. Thank you. Please write the answer below cos I cant set your message as the best one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible reason is that the search index got corrupted. Press the *Search Options* button to the left of *Local Search*, to open the Search Option window:

[image]

On the *Index* tab, press *Delete Index* to delete the index, and have it rebuilt by ArcGIS.